# UIViewController issue

Tags: iphone

I want to get objects values from a UIViewController.

I am using this

> SecondViewController *newObject=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];

But newobject has textview, its value is zero. How can I access the textview?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the textview as a property to be able to access it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the initialization process is incorrect:
If you use NIB file for you view then you should use

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

to initialize your controller. If you create your view programmatically, you must override controller's -loadView method. (see UIViewController reference for details)

Edit: Make sure that your textview is connected to some controller's outlet in the nib file.